# PHP mt_rand() function

Tags: php

Are PHP random numbers predictable? if so, how difficult would it be to predict random numbers that are in a range of 1 to 32? and is there any way to make it unpredictable?

```
<?php
function rand_best($min, $max) {
    $generated = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
        $generated[] = mt_rand($min, $max);
    }
    shuffle($generated);
    $position = mt_rand(0, 99);
    return $generated[$position];
}
?>
```

Comment: Since you are using `mt_rand()`, you should read up on the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) algorithm if you want to know how it works.

Comment: Additionally, `mt_rand()` provides better quality than `rand()` (which is notably flawed). BTW, *not random*, *not uniform* and *predictable* are pretty different concepts: you just can't predict the next number if you don't know the seed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The discussion around how random random-functions in programming is, is ancient.

Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Anyway. The random-functions are so good today that they are (what I would call) as near random as possible. There's no way to predict a result between 1,32 (or any other number for that sake). The deal is that the numbers are not truly random because a computer can not do such a operation.

I'd say the rand-functions is more than good enough unless you are writing something for Pentagon

Comment: Some computers have hardware devices producing really random numbers.

Comment: That's true. I've read on this page http://www.random.org/randomness/ (should be read!) that they use a radioactive source, because they are truly random.

Comment: I think the some very latest Intel processors have a random generating privileged instruction.

Comment: "Writing for the Pentagon" or even more intense: making an HTTPS request. Seriously, good randomness sources are needed everywhere or things as we know them wouldn't function at all. I don't think it's right to shove the concept under the rug because it might not be immediately intuitive. You don't need radioactive sources for those basic cases either, and [all modern kernels are able to gather good-enough randomness from common sources to feed a pool used for seeding PRNGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28computing%29). [On-topic answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/18033).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a Linux system, you could seed your pseudo random number generator with [/dev/urandom](http://linux.die.net/man/4/random) (or read from that), or possibly `/dev/random` (be careful, it can block).

Answer (score 1):

After PHP 7 version you can use `random_int()` too. 

Take a look at this: http://php.net/random_int